# Disable buttons in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, repeater

How do I access a particular row in asp Repeater and disable the buttons in it ? This program disables all the down buttons. I want to check if the userId exists in Database it should disable the up button and only the down button should be enabled.

```
  public void Repeater1_ItemDatabound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            String userID = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1]; 
             if (isOwner(userID) == true)
             {

                 Button b = e.Item.FindControl("btnmoveup") as Button;
                    b.Enabled = false;


            }

public bool isOwner(string user_ID)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ctd_priority_dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select POwner from Projects WHERE POwner = @userid", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", user_ID);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That looks fine, albeit the isOwner method querying on every item represents poor practices.

Comment: And what happens with your program ? Some error ? Have you tried JQuery ?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/1793pk/6 this is what I want ... all the buttons are enabled on the right hand side ... I just want the buttons beside my name to be enabled

Comment: In your isOwner method, the method return true ?

Comment: yes ... but since it finds the powner it will disable all the buttons I want it to disable only the buttons next to my name

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question...

But one technique I've used for enabled, visible, and other properties is to pull that value into the query you're using to fill your repeater.  For example, your query / stored procedure could return a column called 'is_enabled' that has 1 or 0 as the value.  Then your button's .enabled property could be set like this: `.enabled = '<%# eval(is_enabled) %>'`

hope that helps

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/1793pk/6
I am just a beginner and dont have much idea about it 
can i access the rows with my userID and just disable the buttons ? 
if (isOwner(userID) == true)
             {

                 Button b = e.Item.FindControl("btnmoveup") as Button;
                    b.Enabled = false;
}

Comment: Right now, you're running two queries.  First, you're filling your repeater.  Second, you're iterating through your repeater, and running a query to determin POwner (over and over and over, for each repeater row).  Rather than do that, why not try to determine POwner in your first query -- the one that originally fills your repeater?  Does that make sense?  Beyond that, the code in my answer would be added directly to your markup -- presumably, you've got some markup for your repeater that includes an asp:button...

Comment: I do understand what you said but I dont think I can implement this .. its been only a month since I started asp.net ... while iterating through the rows for Powner can I find out the index of the row where it matches ?